# Python3 http.server: changing index.html to index.py

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, cgi

Is there a way to change `index.html` to `index.py` in Python http.server? Now if someone loads mysite.com, index.html is loading. But I want to execute cgi script in index.py. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

set it in you `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
AddHandler application/x-httpd-cgi .py
DirectoryIndex index.py
```

for example `index.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "test"
```

or for testing the python use the os module to execute the command:

```
import os
from django.shortcuts import render

def command_view(request):
    output = os.popen('ls -l').read()
    return render(request, 'command.html', {'output': output})
```

And put the result of the command into the `<pre>` tag:

```
<pre>{{ output }}</pre>
```

Comment: Where are you getting these from? I can't find any reference anywhere in the midules to htaccess etc